# Why won't my Creep stay still?

Tags: screeps

I've commanded a bunch of creeps to certain positions but when I command this particular one it just keeps spazzing out. I've done nothing different from how I controlled the other creeps but it doesn't work the same. The other ones stay still.

```
if(creep == Game.creeps["Transport1"])
{
    creep.moveTo(harvesterLoc.x, harvesterLoc.y - 2);
    creep.transferEnergy(Game.creeps["Transport2"]);
}
if(creep == Game.creeps["Transport2"])
{
    creep.moveTo(harvesterLoc.x, harvesterLoc.y - 3);
    creep.transferEnergy(Game.spawns.spawn1);
}
```

The first one works, but the 2nd one doesn't? The location for the 2nd one is within the ramparts, does that cause an issue?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in this line:

```
if(creep = Game.creeps["Transport1"])
```

Replace `=` with `==` like this:

```
if(creep == Game.creeps["Transport1"])
```

`=` is the assignment operator, `==` is the equality operator. More about operators in JS in [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Comment: I feel so stupid now, but the same thing is still happening after changing to the comparative ==. the one on the ramparts keeps goingn diagonally down right then back

Comment: Also check the spawn's name in `Game.spawns.spawn1` - probably it is `Spawn1` with the uppercase `S`. Otherwise, there might be some issues in your logic which can't be traced using only this piece of code.

Comment: That's not the issue either. If i replace the move to with `creep.moveTo(23,27);` it works fine, but if I do `creep.moveTo(23,27);` it doesn't work. Any location will work it seems as long as it's not the rampart. If the location I tell them to move to is the rampart they will move off it, and then back onto it rapidly. There's no where else that moves this creep

Comment: I've also noticed that when I moveTo(Game.spawns.spawn) the units actually don't end up on the rampart but one block away